# Why does unzipping a file in C# create UnauthorizedAccessException for the next file action?

Tags: c#, exception, unzip

Trying to tidy up my code, so I moved the method that handles a user selecting a file for unzipping into a central  fileops class. It is now throwing an UnathorisedAccessException and I can't figure it out.

The workflow is that the user selects the zipped log file they want to look at via FileOps.UnzipFile() (called by my ViewModel), it gets unzipped and then the FileOps.UnzipFile() returns the location of the unzipped file.

However, when the ViewModel tries:
`var lines = File.ReadLines(unZippedFilePath); //read the unzipped file`
I get an UnauthorizedAccessException....

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
private void ProcessLogFile(object parameter)
        {

            
            string unZippedFilePath =  WGFileOperations.UnzipFile();


            var lines = File.ReadLines(unZippedFilePath); //read the unzipped file

            foreach (var lineCheck in lines)
            {

            /* do a bunch of stuff  */
                
            }

            //BORING STUFF OMMITED
}
```

The WGFileOperations.UnzipFile() method looks like this:

```
public static string UnzipFile()
        {

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            string _filePath = null;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                _filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_filePath);

            saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;


            string extractPath = @"C:\Orica\UnpackedFiles\" + _filePath; //default extractpath


            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                extractPath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            }
           
            if (File.Exists(extractPath) == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(_filePath, extractPath);
                    MessageBox.Show("File Created Ok I Guess Because I Didn't Throw An Exception!");
                    
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error attempting to extract file! " + ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("That file already exists");
            }

            return extractPath;

        }
```

So any ideas why this might be occurring and what I can do about it? It is working fine when I have the WGFileOps.UnzipFile() method in the ViewModel...

Comment: `ExtractToDirectory` will create a directory with the given name and put the unzipped file(s) in it. So your `unZippedFilePath` is a directory path, not a file path.

Comment: Haha perfect... spot on. Working perfectly now that I've added some code to grab the file not the dir. Many thanks Klaus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klaus nailed the issue:
"ExtractToDirectory will create a directory with the given name and put the unzipped file(s) in it. So your unZippedFilePath is a directory path, not a file path".

I was returning a directory path to my method, which was looking for a file path. As a result I was getting the access exception. To fix the issue I inserted some code to obtain the actual file path and then passed this to my method. Now everything works nicely and I feel better about life knowing my code is a little cleaner ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with FileStream, something like this:

```
 using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
 {
     using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
     {
         foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
         {
             if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
             {
                 using (var stream = entry.Open())
                 using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                 {
                     string line;
                     while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                     {
                          // read your lines here
                     }  
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi... Thanks, that does look like a better way to structure it. I might try that next time!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**